# Is it possible that an home-made app reboot android devices

Tags: android

I created an app for Android and run it on Android 4.1.2. Some time my device reboot, I'm wondering if it is possible that due to a bug the android reboot?

I thought only the app could crash!

Details on the app:
The app runs to services in background to collect data via REST API. I use the AlarmManager to relaunch periodically the onStartService to collect the data.

Permissions:

```
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Do you think it is possible that my app crash android or it is something else?

Thx
Dominique

Comment: One of the webapp I use, uses Google Maps API and when I haven't install gapps after flashing ROM using that application causes a restart. That may be the case for you also. Some service that your device doesn't maybe called by your application. IDK, this is the first thing comes to my mind

Comment: Thx but my Android device reboot randomly and not each time I use my app. Is it possible that a memory leak make the device reboot?

Comment: For test I removed the app from my device and install it on another one. Both devices are working fine for the time being... The device without the app doesn't crash anymore and the devices with the app didn't crash yet... So, no conclusion... is it my app or the device???? The only difference is the old device run 4.1.2 and the new one 4.2.2